# the ability to adjust the range of the pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, pivot-table

Good day,

Is it possible to create a macro via VBA to update the range of the pivot table to the last column and row of a dynamic data sheet?

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely

Comment: If you're asking if a VBA macro can change the data range of the pivot cache that is connected to a pivot table, the answer is yes.

Comment: If you mean that you would like the range for the source data to automatically adjust as rows are added or removed, first convert your data into a table (Ribbon  >> Insert >> Tables >> Table), and then when creating your pivot table refer to your data by its table name.